# All JQuery suddenly stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am suddenly having a problem on my website when no jquery scripts are working.

I've clicked on the script library links to see if the host is down and its now.

See here:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I find out what's wrong ... any ideas on what to check?

Comment: have you checked the error console?

Comment: it's now or it's not, that is the question...

Comment: im just curious why are you adding jquery twice?

Comment: @Kishore He's not, one of them is jQuery and the other is jQuery UI.

Comment: just use /1/ to use the latest version of jquery/ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check it in a Chrome or Safari. Open the inspector and check the network and console tabs - one or both will have an error to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin **droparea** is not loaded.
The script needs the plugin "droparea". Just load the plugin, it will work fine.

Or else try the noconflict method : http://www.adrogen.com/blog/jquery-conflict-is-not-a-function/

It will be good if you post the code here !